# how do i display each word of string with different color in UITextfield

Tags: iphone, text, uicolor

I am using UILable to display data. 
I have one NSString @"Hello How are you?". I want to display each word in different color. For Example Hello - in red Color , How - in yellow color etc.

I tried lot but I don't find any solution for this. Is there any idea to anyone How can i get solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use :

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.text.text];

     NSArray *words=[self.text.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

     NSArray *colors=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor grayColor],[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor purpleColor],nil];

    for (NSString *word in words) {        
        NSRange range=[self.text.text rangeOfString:word];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:colors[arc4random()%colors.count] range:range];
    }
    [self.text setAttributedText:string];
}
```

**[Working project here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6090101/ios-each-word-different-color-63k?da=y)*

Comment: Getting Crash in this line... [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:colors[arc4random()%colors.count] range:range];

Comment: @Ganapathy: check the link in answer

Comment: no. I think you are using XCode4.3 or previous., so your compiler is not able to recognize [index].

Comment: @Ganapathy: are you able to download that program and run?

Comment: No. That site is blocked here(in my place).

Comment: @Ganapathy: send your mail id

Answer (score 0):

I'll would add

```
YOURTEXTFIELD.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:18.0f];
```

or whatever is your desired font size because the above function will have terrible results if the user press the space bar twice (or have multiple spaces). 
So the function will become:

code:

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.text.text];

     NSArray *words=[self.text.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

     NSArray *colors=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor],[UIColor grayColor],[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor blackColor],[UIColor purpleColor],nil];

    for (NSString *word in words) {        
        NSRange range=[self.text.text rangeOfString:word];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:colors[arc4random()%colors.count] range:range];
YOURTEXTFIELD.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:18.0f];

    }
    [self.text setAttributedText:string];
YOURTEXTFIELD.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:18.0f];


}
```

Try it!